# Merge two lists jquery by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, merge

Lets say we have this markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Where the format of the `<li>` are such as:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <span class="title">Title of the article</span>
     <span class="date" data-value="[TIMESTAMP]">Pretty Date</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

What i need to do is:

- If the viewport width is big enough: show both lists
- If the viewport width is small: merge both lists by date

  > var min = 760; $(window).resize(function(){
  >       var width = $(window).width();
  >       if(width <= min){
  >           merge_lists();
  >       } });

where i have some trouble figuring out how to do it:

```
function merge_lists(){
     /* shall i run 2 .each function and store it in an array, order by date (how?) and
        regenerate a new list?
      */
}
```

Comment: is TIMESTAMP is in Particular date format or just unix time? show value of TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you like something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
         <span class="title">Title of the article</span>
         <span class="date" data-value="2012/05/01">2012/05/01</span>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
         <span class="title">Title of the article</span>
         <span class="date" data-value="2012/05/05">2012/05/05</span>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
         <span class="title">Title of the article</span>
         <span class="date" data-value="2012/04/10">2012/04/10</span>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var mainlists = $('#container ul'),
    min = 550;

function merge_lists() {
     if (!$('#container').hasClass('merged')) {
        var temp = mainlists.clone(true),
            lists = $('li', temp);
        lists.sort(function(a, b) {
            var d1 = $('span.date', a).data('value'),
                d2 = $('span.date', b).data('value');
            if (new Date(d1).getTime() > new Date(d2).getTime()) return 1;
        });
        $('#container').empty().append($('<ul>', {
            html: lists
        }));
        $('#container').addClass('merged');
    }
}

function restore_lists() {
    if ($('#container').hasClass('merged')) {
       $('#container').empty().append(mainlists.clone(true));
       $('#container').removeClass('merged');
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width(),
        winHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#resolution').html(winWidth + 'px x ' + winHeight + 'px');
    if (winWidth < min) {
        merge_lists();
        $('body').css('background', '#ddd');
    } else {
        restore_lists();
        $('body').css('background', '#fff');
    }
});
```

- **[sort() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**
- **[jquery data()](http://docs.jquery.com/Data)**
- **[getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5whus/15/)**

Comment: Hey! seems to work! but check this out. i added a new container, to keep the separted lists in case user resizes the screen agan. the thing is that still does the job but the original lists seem to get lost somehow: http://jsfiddle.net/5whus/3/ any idea?

Comment: Almost works. But it seems to create a new '<ul>' for each '<li>', check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/5whus/10/ (if you could edit that version would be awesome)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet hi, I update my fiddle again as your comment, test that

Comment: cant get it workig for now. i did a mix yourcode+window.resize: http://jsfiddle.net/5whus/13/ it merges. but it's not well ordenated and it doesn't restore properly...

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Ah, I think your problem has been resolved, check demo

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet do you check the demo?